# how to pass Item description and Price to paypal page asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I am trying to pass course description and price when redirecting to paypal page when user clicks "Buy Now" button. I am not sure how to code for this,and I am new to asp .net c#. Please help me. Below is html and c# code.

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASHAConnectionString %>"  
         SelectCommand="SELECT [TEMPLATE_NAME], [Price] FROM [TemplateMaster]">
   </asp:SqlDataSource>

     <asp:GridView ID="gvPayPalPrice" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gvPayPalPrice_RowCommand"  
            BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84">

          <RowStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" BackColor="#FFF7E7" />
           <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="TEMPLATE_NAME" 
                     HeaderText="TEMPLATE_NAME" SortExpression="TEMPLATE_NAME" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Buy Now">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnBuyNow" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/buy_now.png" Width="64" Height="64" CommandName="buy" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my c# code for passing to paypal page.

```
protected void gvPayPalPrice_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "buy")
    {
        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)e.CommandSource;
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(ib.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row =gvPayPalPrice.Rows[index];

        //Pay pal process Refer for what are the variable are need to send http://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_std-variable-ref-buy-now.html

        string redirectUrl = "";

        //Mention URL to redirect content to paypal site
        redirectUrl += "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paypalemail"].ToString();

        //First name I assign static based on login details assign this value
        redirectUrl += "&first_name=Joe_Seller";

        //Product Name
       redirectUrl += "&item_name=" + CourseName.Text;

        //Product Amount
        redirectUrl += "&amount=" + CoursePrice.Text;

        //Business contact paypal EmailID
        redirectUrl += "&business=joekhaung@outlook.com";

        //Quantiy of product, Here statically added quantity 1
        redirectUrl += "&quantity=1";

        //If transactioin has been successfully performed, redirect SuccessURL page- this page will be designed by developer
        redirectUrl += "&return=" +      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessURL"].ToString();


        //If transactioin has been failed, redirect FailedURL page- this page will be designed by developer
        redirectUrl += "&cancel_return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedURL"].ToString();

        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is just building a Payments Standard URL.  All you need to do is add the [individual shopping cart item parameters](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HH0D0TA) to your string in order to get those to show up like you want.

Here's a rough example of what you want to end up with...

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=some@email.com
&first_name=Tester&last_name=Testerson&amount=10.00
&return={your_return_url}&cancel={your_cancel_url}
&item_name_1=Test Widget #1&amount_1=5.00
&item_name_2=Test Widget #2&item_amount=5.00
```

I've split that into separate lines to make it easier to read here, but of course that would just be one long string / URL.

So you'll probably be looping through some item array of some sort, and you can generate that portion of the URL and then append it to the rest just like you're already doing here.